# Why does scale move my sub-menu below the other lists?

Tags: css, scale

I have a question about `css3 scale`, please see my  [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/muki/bsDmU/)

When the mouse hovers `link1`, the sub-menu will appear but `row-2` will overlay them. But if I comment out `-webkit-transform: scale(.9,.9);`, `row-2` won't overlay sub-menu in `link1` from `row-1`.

I have no idea why `scale` would do this, does anyone have some experience with the same situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following:

```
ul > li {
    float: left;
    -webkit-transform: scale(.9, .9);
    position:relative; /* This is required */
}
ul li:hover {
    z-index:1; /* This is also required */
}
```

This is because the child `ul` elements have `position:absolute`, so you need the `position:relative` on the parent since the `transform` on the parent creates a new stacking context. That new stacking context prevents the child `ul` from displaying over the other `li` elements

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/bsDmU/2/)